# Getting error "Unable to read entire header" when created file through apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, export-to-excel, xssf, poi-hssf

```
I am using Java and POI 3.7 and I want to perform following in xlWrite() function-
1. Check the file. If it doesn't exist create a new one.
   If file exists, delete it and create a new one. 
   (DO I have to delete it or if it exists already my new content will overwrite it?) 
2. Once check in 1. is completed, create a new sheet in the workbook if it doesn't exists.
```

---

Questions:

1. In XL write function I get above exception if I uncomment part of creating a file. Otherwise it works fine. What should I change in my program to achieve what I want?
2. I am not sure. Should I use HSSF or XSSF? Which is good. Right now I have to save my Excel as .xls to run the program. It doesn't accept .xlsx. What should I do?

---

I have created a xl class to perform read and write operations on Excel and I will be
 calling these functions from my script.
Program I wrote is as given below but I get exception -

```
package lampsplus.utilities;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;


public class XLOperations{

    //variables declaration
    private int i,j,k;
    private int xRows, xCols;
    private String xlData[][];
    private HSSFRow row;
    private HSSFCell cell;
    private File xlFile;
    private FileInputStream inStream;
    private FileOutputStream outStream;
    private HSSFWorkbook workbook;
    private HSSFSheet sheet;

    /**
     * This method returns XL read from file.
     *
     * @return String[][]  - two dimensional array of read data. 
     */ 
    public String[][] getXLData()
    {
        return xlData;
    }


    /**
     * Class constructor to initialize variables.
     *
     */ 
     public void XLOperations()
     {
         System.out.println("initializing constructor dboperations:");
         this.xlData= null;
         this.row = null;
         this.cell = null;
         this.xlFile = null;
         this.inStream = null;
         this.outStream = null;
         this.workbook = null;
         this.sheet = null;
     }



    /**
     * This method is for reading a excel file in two dimensional array. 
     *
     * @param String - filePath - Path of the file from where to read the information.
     * @param String - sheetName -Name of the sheet to read from file. 
     * @return void
     * @throws Exception - An unexpected exception
     */ 
    public void xlRead(String filePath,String sheetName) throws Exception
    {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        filePath= file.getAbsolutePath(); 

        xlFile = new File(filePath);
        inStream = new FileInputStream(xlFile);
        workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inStream);
        sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);  
        xRows = sheet.getLastRowNum()+1  ;
        xCols = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
        xlData = new String[xRows][xCols];

        for(i=0;i<xRows;i++)
        {
            row = sheet.getRow(i);
            for(j=0;j<xCols;j++)
            {
                cell = row.getCell(j);
                String value = cellToString(cell);
                xlData[i][j] = value;
            } 
        } 
    }    


    /**
     * This method is for writing a writing a excel sheet into a file. 
     *
     * @param String - filePath 
     * @param String - sheetname 
     * @param string - two dimensional array to write in the file
     * @return void
     * @throws Exception - An unexpected exception
     */ 
    public void xlWrite(String filePath,String sheetName,String data[][]) throws Exception
    {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        filePath= file.getAbsolutePath(); 


        xlFile = new File(filePath);

    /*   if(!xlFile.exists())
         {
                System.out.println("Created file");
             xlFile.createNewFile();
         }   
         */

        inStream = new FileInputStream(xlFile);
        workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inStream);
        k = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
        if(k!=-1)
        {   
            workbook.removeSheetAt(k);
        }   
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(sheetName);
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(xlFile);


        xRows = data.length;
        xCols = data[0].length;
        for(i =0;i<xRows;i++)
        {
            row = sheet.createRow(i);
            for(j=0;j<xCols;j++)
            {
                cell = row.createCell(j);
                cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                cell.setCellValue(data[i][j]);
            } 

        } 
        workbook.write(fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
    }      

    public String cellToString(HSSFCell cell)
    {
        int type = cell.getCellType();
        Object result;
        switch(type)
        {
        case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC: //0
            result = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                break;
        case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING://1
            result = cell.getStringCellValue();
                break;
        case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA://2
            throw new RuntimeException("Java can't evaluate formulas");
        case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK://3
            result = "";
                break;
        case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN://4
            result = cell.getBooleanCellValue();
                break;
        case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR://5
            throw new RuntimeException("This cell has an error");
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("We don't support this cell type:" + type);
        } 
        return result.toString();
    } 

}
```

Exception which I get-

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to read entire header; 0 bytes read; expected 32 bytes
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlockReader.alertShortRead(HeaderBlockReader.java:176)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlockReader.<init>(HeaderBlockReader.java:103)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.<init>(POIFSFileSystem.java:153)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:305)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:286)
    at tryIng.xlWrite(tryIng.java:74)
    at tryIng.main(tryIng.java:49)
```

Comment: Your question is very hard to read - could you fix the formatting?

Comment: I have updated it. Is it easy to understand it now?

Comment: If the file exists and you want to replace it, why are you bothering to load it and delete all the sheets? Why not simply delete the whole file at the file level, then always re-create it?

Comment: Thanks Gagravarr. If file exists I will deleted the whole file and recreate the new one. Right now when I create a file - it works but I get exception when I try to  read it after creating it. Do you have any idea how can I overcome this error?

Comment: It works for everyone else, and it works in all the POI unit tests... You'll need to work out the smallest possible example that works, and the smallest one that doesn't, and post it as an update to your question. The code at the moment is too long to identify any specific issues]

Comment: Hi Gagravarr. Thanks for your reply. I saw your correct replies to many POI questions and those were helpful to me too.  As per your suggestion, I have added a new question with easy code . Please help me to find a solution to it. -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29236294/getting-error-your-inputstream-was-neither-an-ole2-stream-nor-an-ooxml-stream