# Getting error "Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream" when created file through apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf, poi-hssf

I am trying to check if my excel file already exists. If it doesn't exists, I want to create a new one and if it exists I will delete it and create a new one. I wrote following program but I am getting error at line - workbook= WorkbookFactory.create(instream);

The error is->
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:89)
    at tryIng.main(tryIng.java:84)

Here is a program ->

```
 try {
                String filePath= "C:/Users/pritik/Desktop/t1.xlsx";
                File file = new File(filePath);
                filePath= file.getAbsolutePath(); 
                xlFile = new File(filePath);

                if(xlFile.exists() && !xlFile.isDirectory())
                    xlFile.delete(); //delete if file already exists.
                xlFile.createNewFile();

                inStream = new FileInputStream(xlFile);
                workbook =  WorkbookFactory.create(inStream);  // I get error at this line
                String sheetName="NewSheet";
                Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(sheetName);
                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(xlFile);

                int i,j;
                xRows = xTS.length;
                xCols = xTS[0].length;
                for(i =0;i<xRows;i++)
                {
                    row = sheet.createRow(i);
                    for(j=0;j<xCols;j++)
                    {
                        cell = row.createCell(j);
                        cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                        cell.setCellValue(xTS[i][j]);
                    } 
                } 
                workbook.write(fOut);
                fOut.flush();
                fOut.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't create an empty file and try to read it, that won't work. An empty zero byte file is not valid, and can't be loaded Instead, have POI create an new file for you, which you will write later.

Change the code:

```
if(xlFile.exists() && !xlFile.isDirectory())
    xlFile.delete(); //delete if file already exists.
xlFile.createNewFile();

inStream = new FileInputStream(xlFile);          
workbook =  WorkbookFactory.create(inStream);
```

To instead be:

```
if(xlFile.exists() && !xlFile.isDirectory())
    xlFile.delete(); //delete if file already exists.

if (xlFile.toString().endsWith(".xls") {
   workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
} else {
   workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
}
```

Also, if you do want to read an existing file, don't use a stream if you have a file! See [this bit of the POI docs](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream) for why not.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gagravarr. It works fine. I also read the information you provided in the link and I changed my code. Thanks again.

Comment: @Gagravarr why are you not using Workbook factory and using hss and xssf workbook is there any reason

Comment: @Labeo WorkbookFactory is only for reading existing files. The OP wants to create a new one from scratch

Comment: Yeah i am having files that already exists but still i am getting the error

Comment: @Labeo Check what the file really is then, not what the extension says. The Apache Tika app in `--detect` mode should tell you

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to choose the implementation classes based on the file extension described in the accepted answer.

If you are working with XLSX (Excel 2007+ format), you should include the `poi-ooxml` dependency in your project. If you are working with XLS (Excel 97-2003 format), you should include the `poi` dependency.

For XLSX (Excel 2007+):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

At the end to work with xlsx and xls, you need two dependencies

**First**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

**Second**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```